# How to make select dropdown as a Rails instead of HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to simpler code using Rails e.g I have an HTML dropdown code like below

```
<label>Job City</label>
<select name="job[city_ids][]" id="job_city_ids" class="form-control">
    <% City.all.each do |city| %>
        <option value="<%= city.id %>">
            <%= city.name %>
        </option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

above code are fine, working as expected e.g select one and insert this.

I want to convert something like this as a Rails

```
<%= select_tag(:city_ids, options_for_select(...)) %>
```

Till now if you not clear my consept then my question is below.

Q: How to convert above HTML code to as a Rails.

**Update**

```
#job.rb
has_many :job_cities, dependent: :destroy
has_many :cities, through: :job_cities

#jobs_controller.rb
def new
    @job = Job.new
end

def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    @job.employer = current_employer

    respond_to do |format|
        if @job.save
            flash[:success] = 'Job was successfully created.'
            format.html { redirect_to job_path(@job) }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @job, :status => :created, :location => @job }
        else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @job.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end

private

def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:company_id, :title, :details, :no_of_vacancies, :deadline, :requirements, :years_of_experience,  :is_hb_apply,city_ids: [], category_ids: [])
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, 'id', 'name')
```

See here for complete documentation:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was tried this before but not inserting data, while I use multiple to this which you provided then it's inserting data but this allow to multi select dropdown that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a Job Model that has_many :cities (or something similar). In you new or edit controller you set @job (with new or find). Then you can do the following.

```
<%= form_for @job do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select (:city_ids, City.all, :id, :name, 
      { :prompt => "Select cities" }, { :multiple => true } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Same bro. If I use multiple true then submit the data but allow multiple selection, when remove the multiple then it not saving data. It has_many through association. I need allow to one selection & submit that